# MySQL order By date time field, then Rand() if same dates exist

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with around 10 columns, one of them is a `date_time` field.

Sometimes I need to retrieve some rows ordered by `date_time DESC`, but also need them sorted randomly if there are an exact two or more rows with the exact same time.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY created_at DESC, RAND()
```

But, I test it and always give ve the same order, even if I manually edit three fields to have the exact same date_time value. I need those rows randomly ordered if they have the same edited time.

Complete query:

```
$query = "SELECT items.*, 
              user_data.s_name, 
              user_data.s_email, 
              user_data.s_phone_mobile, 
              item_info.s_title, 
              item_info.s_description,
              item_region.fk_i_region_id,
              pictures.pk_i_id AS picture_name, pictures.s_extension, pictures.s_path,
              (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meta.s_value SEPARATOR '|$|') FROM oc_t_item_meta meta WHERE meta.fk_i_item_id = items.pk_i_id) AS metadata
              FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "t_item items 
              JOIN " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "t_user user_data ON items.fk_i_user_id = user_data.pk_i_id 
              JOIN " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "t_item_description item_info ON items.pk_i_id = item_info.fk_i_item_id 
              JOIN " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "t_item_location item_region ON items.pk_i_id = item_region.fk_i_item_id
              LEFT OUTER JOIN " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "t_item_resource pictures ON items.pk_i_id = pictures.fk_i_item_id
              WHERE items.fk_i_category_id = " . $catId . " 
              AND items.dt_mod_date > '" . $week . " 00:00:00'
              GROUP BY items.pk_i_id
              ORDER BY items.dt_mod_date DESC, RAND()";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Beware that `RAND` is going to cause a full table scan and make the query very very slow. Could you randomise the order in PHP?

Comment: Yes, it´s dangerous I suppose, even with some limits and where´s? I´ll edit the question for complete query analysis.

Comment: I'll add a PHP answer :)

Comment: For the record, this query runs only once a week, in very low load time, around 2 am, just for third party service.

Comment: I'm curious... would `SELECT ... RAND() AS \`random\` WHERE ... ORDER BY \`random\` `still require a full table scan?

Comment: @Jerry did you manage to get my answer working?

Answer (score 2):

As `RAND` will make your query run extremely slow, you could instead sort in PHP. For example, the following code will sort the dates descending, or randomly if they are the same:

```php
$data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'dt_mod_date' => '2017-01-01'],
    ['id' => 2, 'dt_mod_date' => '2017-01-01'],
    ['id' => 3, 'dt_mod_date' => '2017-01-01'],
    ['id' => 5, 'dt_mod_date' => '2017-01-03'],
    ['id' => 4, 'dt_mod_date' => '2017-01-02'],
];

usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['dt_mod_date'] === $b['dt_mod_date']) {
        return (bool) mt_rand(0, 1);
    }

    return strtotime($a['dt_mod_date']) < strtotime($b['dt_mod_date']);
});


var_dump($data);

//     Result
//    array(5) {
//        [0] =>
//      array(2) {
//            'id' =>
//        int(5)
//        'dt_mod_date' =>
//        string(10) "2017-01-03"
//      }
//      [1] =>
//      array(2) {
//            'id' =>
//        int(4)
//        'dt_mod_date' =>
//        string(10) "2017-01-02"
//      }
//      [2] =>
//      array(2) {
//            'id' =>
//        int(1)
//        'dt_mod_date' =>
//        string(10) "2017-01-01"
//      }
//      [3] =>
//      array(2) {
//            'id' =>
//        int(3)
//        'dt_mod_date' =>
//        string(10) "2017-01-01"
//      }
//      [4] =>
//      array(2) {
//            'id' =>
//        int(2)
//        'dt_mod_date' =>
//        string(10) "2017-01-01"
//      }
//    }
```